# Duplicate Inner div inside of the Outer div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to duplicate some divs. I am able to do this, however, when my div is duplicated it is being duplicated on top of my other content. I would like for it to be duplicated in the same div but it seems to be doing it outside of the div. Below is my code, any suggestions?

I think the problem lies within the last line of the javascript function with the parent node append child but I am not sure.

**JS**

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;

    var i = 0;
    var original = document.getElementById('duplicator');

    function duplicate() {
        var clone = original.cloneNode(true); 
        clone.id = "gamesdiv" + ++i;
        original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    }
</script>
```

**HTML/MARKUP**

```
<div id="gamesdiv">
    <div id="duplicator">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>type</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="gamestype" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="92px"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td>name of game: </td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="namegame" runat="server" Height="17px" Width="118px"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
        </table>   
    </div>
</div>

<button id="button" onclick="duplicate()">Add new game</button>
```

The `gamesdiv` is the div I would like for it to be duplicated in and the 'duplicator' div is the div I am duplicating. If you would like to view my html code please ask

Comment: Could you provide the HTML? I don't think I can really target the issue if I don't see how the `gamesdiv` is being generated.

Comment: @WebWanderer I have included the following code

Comment: It still looks like your code is working as intended, have you used the inspector to make sure the clones aren't being placed in the right div? (right-click > inspect element)

Comment: Yeah I just tested it using this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wx28g/). Seems to be working fine

Comment: @Curlystraw you are correct It is being created in the other div but it seems to be overlapping(generating the duplicated div over my other content on the page) any suggestions how I can maybe get the div to auto expand or something along those lines

Comment: The div should be auto-expanding naturally.  Can you create a fiddle that duplicates your environment (without the asp tags)?  This way we can see your CSS and markup and JS to determine what is causing the side-effect.

Comment: @user3668266 it should automatically resize as elements are added, is it or any of the content it's overlapping set as position: absolute?

Comment: @xDaevax check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wx28g/1/ when you click the button its overlapping the duplication below my other div

Comment: So, you want the div with the description and button to go above the expanding divs, or do you want it to go down as more are added?

Comment: @user3668266 found it! your gamesdiv has a height restriction on it. It's height is permanently set to 85 pixels, so the second div isn't moving. Try changing it to min-height: 85px. That way it'll start at the right size, and if the clones need it to be larger, it'll change in height to fit

Comment: @xDaevax I want the top div to auto expand and the bottom div I created which is called 'gamesdesc' I want that to be underneath all the duplications I add so it is not overlapping

Comment: Edited after I saw you new comment, just do what @Curlystraw suggested to get that effect.

Comment: @xDaevax I still seems to be overlapping It works in the fiddle but not in my program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have two issues:

The first is the gamesdiv height is set to 85, which limits it.

Next, some of the markup has an invalid close (you have a div that looks like `<div/>` instead of `</div>`

I have fixed both of these issues here and tweaked your styles slightly:

http://jsfiddle.net/xDaevax/7LLXZ/

Answer (score 0):

Please check this js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gb69f/

It is solved your problem or not? If not then please tell me what is the problem?

**JavaScript**

```
    document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;

    var i = 0;
    var original = document.getElementById('duplicator');

    function duplicate() {
        var clone = original.cloneNode(true); 
        clone.id = "gamesdiv" + ++i;
        original.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    }
```